# Can a program repeat when a user ends the program while it is running?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

This is a Hi-Lo number guessing game code, and the program ends either when the user gets the correct number or enters -1 while playing the game.

Here, I was wondering if it is possible to make the program run again even after the user enters -1 and the game ends, for example, in a situation where the user feels like restarting the game without finishing the first game.

---

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class HighLowGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random generator = new Random();
    int number =generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
    int count = 0;
    boolean game = true;

    System.out.println("Please guess the number.(Enter -1 to quit): ");

    while(game){
        int guess = scanner.nextInt();

        **//if user enters -1, the game ends
        if(guess == -1){
            break;
        }**

        //guessed number is out of range
        if(guess>100 || guess<0){
            System.out.println("The number should be between 0 and 100.");
        }

        //guessed number is smaller than the random number
        if(guess < number && 0 <= guess && guess <= 100 ){
            count++;
            System.out.println("That is too low. Please try again.(Enter -1 to quit):");
        }

        // guessed number is bigger than the random number
        else if(guess > number && 0 <= guess && guess <= 100){
            count++;
            System.out.println("That is too high. Please try again.(Enter -1 to quit):");
        }

        //guessed number is the same as the random number
        else if(guess==number) {
            count++;
         System.out.println("Congratulations! You got the correct number.");
         System.out.println("Your attempt was " + count + " tries.");
         count = 0;
         System.out.println("Would you like to play the game again?(yes/no): ");
            String another = scanner.next();
            if (another.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                break;
            }

            // if the user wants to play the game one more time, it starts again
            else {
                number = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
                System.out.println("Please guess the number(Enter -1 to quit): ");
                }
            }

       }

    }

 }
```

Comment: What does "*start again*" mean for you? From what point?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/12672179)

Comment: You could just call the main method again `main(args)` or put the code into *another* function and recall that function, or even put it within another loop that does not break until the answer is *not* `-1`

Comment: Instead of breaking after checking for -1, ask the user if they want to play again. If they don't, then break, if not, keep going.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: *"Can I ..."*.  Yes you can.  *"Should I ..."*. That is entirely up to you.  Please clarify your question so that we can understand what you are **really** asking.  Put the clarification into the question itself.  *"I'm sorry that I didn't realize that my question was not very clear. "* - It may help if you read what you have written, and then asked yourself if someone sitting at a desk 10,000 kilometers away would be able to understand it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @RIVERMAN2010 Thanks. I solved the question by moving the break.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thank you for your answer. I solved it by changing the break.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the game into a method, and when the method ends, you just ask them.
Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean flag = true;
    while(flag){
        play();//play the game
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//read the respound
        System.out.println("want to play again?");
        if(input.nextLine().equal("no"){//Want to play? BTW: I'm assuming you only enter "no" or "yes" 
            flag = false;//Don't want to play
        }
   }
}
```

And the method:

```
public static void play(){
//create scanner, variables and a random number
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random generator = new Random();
    int number =generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
    int count = 0;
    boolean game = true;

    //prompt user to enter a number
    System.out.println("Please guess the number.(Enter -1 to quit): ");

    while(game){

        //user enters a number
        int guess = scanner.nextInt();

        //if user enters -1, the game ends
        if(guess == -1){
            break;
        }

        //guessed number is out of range
        if(guess>100 || guess<0){
            System.out.println("The number should be between 0 and 100.");
        }

        //guessed number is smaller than the random number
        if(guess < number && 0 <= guess && guess <= 100 ){
            count++;
            System.out.println("That is too low. Please try again.(Enter -1 to quit):");
        }

        // guessed number is bigger than the random number
        else if(guess > number && 0 <= guess && guess <= 100){
            count++;
            System.out.println("That is too high. Please try again.(Enter -1 to quit):");
        }

        //guessed number is the same as the random number
        else if(guess==number) {
            count++;

            //displays the message and the attempt count
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You got the correct number.");
            System.out.println("Your attempt was " + count + " tries.");

       }

    }
}
```

BTW: you said when the user enters -1, you end the game, then why in the world do you want to ask the user again ?_?

Comment: @beebee12 Ok, but are you fine with this solution? Or want me to write another way?